# How to combine string | REGEX

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

def tst():
  text = '''
  <script>
  '''
  if proxi := re.findall(r"(?:<td\s[^>]*?><font\sclass\=spy14>(.*?)<script.*?\"\+(.*?)\)<\/script)", text):
    for proxy, port in proxi:
      yield f"{proxy}:{''.join(port)}"
    
    if dtt := re.findall(r"<td colspan=1><font class\=spy1><font class\=spy14>(.*?)</font> (\d+[:]\d+) <font class\=spy5>([(]\d+ \w+ \w+[)])", text):
      for date, time, taken in dtt:
        yield f"{date} {' '.join([time, taken])}"
   
    return None
  return None

for proxy in tst():
  print(proxy)
```

output that i get

```
51.155.10.0:8000
178.128.96.80:7497
98.162.96.41:4145
27-oct-2022 11:05 (49 mins ago)
27-oct-2022 11:04 (50 mins ago)
27-oct-2022 11:03 (51 mins ago)
```

so i use this regex below to capture group from output

```
(\w+[.]\w+[.]\w+[.]\w+[:]\w+)|(\w+.*)
```

i want the result like this, how to combine it from output?

```
157.245.247.84:7497 - 27-oct-2022 11:05 (49 mins ago)
184.190.137.213:8111 - 27-oct-2022 11:04 (50 mins ago)
202.149.89.67:7999 - 27-oct-2022 11:03 (51 mins ago)
```

Comment: What is dynamic about your input? The number of lines? The order? What is the common pattern to all possible inputs?

Comment: That doesn't really answer my questions though.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I don't know how to explain it in English. But if you can take a look at the full code, Maybe it can answer your question.

Comment: A question should have all necessary information to understand the question -- it should not be behind a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the code at the top of your (edited) question has regular expressions that work perfectly, **and** they run the same number of matches, you could use `zip`:

```py
import re

def tst():
    text = '''
    <script>
    '''
    proxi = re.findall(r"(?:<td\s[^>]*?><font\sclass\=spy14>(.*?)<script.*?\"\+(.*?)\)<\/script)", text)
    dtt = re.findall(r"<td colspan=1><font class\=spy1><font class\=spy14>(.*?)</font> (\d+[:]\d+) <font class\=spy5>([(]\d+ \w+ \w+[)])", text)
    if proxi and dtt:
        for (proxy, port), (date, time, taken) in zip(proxi, dtt):
            yield f"{proxy}:{''.join(port)} {date} {' '.join([time, taken])}"
   
for proxy in tst():
    print(proxy)
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach reads all lines into a list, then iterates the IP lines and date lines in tandem to generate the output.

```py
text = '''157.245.247.84:7497
184.190.137.213:8111
202.149.89.67:7999
27-oct-2022 11:05 (49 mins ago)
27-oct-2022 11:04 (50 mins ago)
27-oct-2022 11:03 (51 mins ago)'''
lines = text.split('\n')
output = []
for i in range(0, len(lines) / 2):
    val = lines[i] + ' - ' + lines[i + len(lines)/2]
    output.append(val)

print('\n'.join(output))
```

This prints:

```
157.245.247.84:7497 - 27-oct-2022 11:05 (49 mins ago)
184.190.137.213:8111 - 27-oct-2022 11:04 (50 mins ago)
202.149.89.67:7999 - 27-oct-2022 11:03 (51 mins ago)
```

Note that this answer assumes each IP line would always have exactly one matching date line.  It also assumes that the lines are ordered, and that all IP lines come before the date lines.

Comment: I just edit posted. That the question.

Comment: @xnoob The preface of how you end up with the lines doesn't affect the validity of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Providing the text is **guaranteed** to contain N lines of IP addresses followed by N lines of "timestamps" then you could do this:

```
text = '''157.245.247.84:7497
184.190.137.213:8111
202.149.89.67:7999
27-oct-2022 11:05 (49 mins ago)
27-oct-2022 11:04 (50 mins ago)
27-oct-2022 11:03 (51 mins ago)'''

lines = text.splitlines()

for ip, t in zip(lines, lines[len(lines)//2:]):
    print(f'{ip} - {t}')
```

**Output:**

```
157.245.247.84:7497 - 27-oct-2022 11:05 (49 mins ago)
184.190.137.213:8111 - 27-oct-2022 11:04 (50 mins ago)
202.149.89.67:7999 - 27-oct-2022 11:03 (51 mins ago)
```

Comment: i just edit posted. That the question.

Answer (score 1):

using regex

```
import re

text = '''
157.245.247.84:7497
184.190.137.213:8111
202.149.89.67:7999
27-oct-2022 11:05 (49 mins ago)
27-oct-2022 11:04 (50 mins ago)
27-oct-2022 11:03 (51 mins ago)
'''
ip_regex = r"(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\:\d{4}"
time_regex = r'\d{2}\-\w+\-\d{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\(.+\)'

ip_list = re.findall(ip_regex, text)
time_list = re.findall(time_regex, text)

for i in range(len(ip_list)):
    print(f'{ip_list[i]} - {time_list[i]}')


>>> 157.245.247.84:7497 - 27-oct-2022 11:05 (49 mins ago)
>>> 184.190.137.213:8111 - 27-oct-2022 11:04 (50 mins ago)
>>> 202.149.89.67:7999 - 27-oct-2022 11:03 (51 mins ago)
```